# Android Repository Implementation with Interface

Tags: android, repository-pattern, android-mvvm

Usually, I use an Interface for my repositories:

```
interface UserRepository {
    fun add()
    fun get(userId): User
    .....
}
```

I have three types of Repositories (InMemory, Database, and Network):

They all implement UserRepository:
`UserInMemoryRepository` - `UserDatabaseRepository` - `UserNetworkRepository`

But my network **doesn't** have any **add user** API

What is the best practice here?

1. Remove my UserRepository interface
2. Leave an empty add user method
3. ...... (Any better approach)

Comment: You should have only one RepositoryImpl, inside it has logic when getting data from memory or database or network

Comment: @CôngHải That's not how Google Samples implement this

Comment: Please take a look here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide. Inside UserRepository it manage both memory cached and remote network.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving `add()` empty doesn't goes in pair with SOLID principles.
If more than one class should override some method, then you shouldn't remove interface either.
What I would do is create interface:

```
interface Repository {
    fun get(userId): User
}
...
interface UserRepository : Repository {
     fun add()
}
```

Then your "Network" can implement `Repository`, and the rest of classes implement `UserRepository`.
Of course naming of interfaces is up to you, but according to 'I' in SOLID it is better to have more dedicated interfaces rather than one multifunctional